# Applying filters in Sensu

Tags: monitoring, sensu, uchiwa

I have tried applying a filter in Sensu, from referring Sensu document, for reducing our monitoring alerts. But problem is, this filter is sending email only when issue is in Resolved state, no critical or warning alerts. Filter looks like :

```
{
  "filters": {
    "state_change_only": {
      "negate": false,
      "attributes": {
        "occurrences": "eval: value == 1 || ':::action:::' == 'resolve'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me in understanding this behaviour and what this `eval: value == 1` actually means here.

Does it have to do anything with **occurrences** value? I have values like 2,3 etc. depending on the severity of the checks.

Comment: Yes, the first eval statement is looking at the value of the occurrences field. I’m surprised new warning or critical events aren’t being passed through to the handler as-is. Have you tried removing the OR statement in the eval to see what happens? You should get an email on all first occurrences of an event, and only the first.

Comment: @Myles I found that max value of occurrences in my checks was 3, so i tried something like `eval: value < 4 || ':::action:::' == 'resolve'"`, i started getting Critcal, Warning alerts as well along with Resolved alerts.